# Flutter camera back button crashes the app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm writing an app that's focused on camera. My main problem is, that when I press back button on the camera screen, the app exits as normal, but then it crashes in the background. I think I've handled the dispose handler correctly:

```
@override
void dispose() async {
  await _controller?.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

The controller is a camera controller. At first I had it without async/await but it acted the same.
When it crashes I get this in the output:

```
D/InputMethodManager(19934): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@51d4f30[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(19934): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/InputTransport(19934): Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=104
D/SurfaceView(19934): onWindowVisibilityChanged(8) false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{57ae460 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,2136} of ViewRootImpl@2c02e5c[MainActivity]
D/SurfaceView(19934): surfaceDestroyed callback.size 1 #2 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{57ae460 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,2136}
I/mali_egl(19934): eglDestroySurface() in
I/mali_winsys(19934): delete_surface() [1080x2136] return
I/mali_egl(19934): eglDestroySurface() out
W/libEGL  (19934): EGLNativeWindowType 0x7b9986a010 disconnect failed
D/SurfaceView(19934): remove() io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{57ae460 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,2136} Surface(name=SurfaceView - io.memoo.app/io.memoo.app.MainActivity@57ae460@0)/@0x6d79b9
D/OpenGLRenderer(19934): makeCurrent EglSurface : 0x7b9975f480 -> 0x0
D/OpenGLRenderer(19934): destroyEglSurface : 0x7b9975f480
I/mali_egl(19934): eglDestroySurface() in
I/mali_winsys(19934): delete_surface() [1080x2280] return
I/mali_egl(19934): eglDestroySurface() out
W/libEGL  (19934): EGLNativeWindowType 0x7b99f01510 disconnect failed
D/OpenGLRenderer(19934): ~ReliableSurface : 0x7b99f01500
D/ViewRootImpl@2c02e5c[MainActivity](19934): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2280) new=(0,0,1080,2280) req=(1080,2280)8 dur=5 res=0x5 s={false 0} ch=true
D/ViewRootImpl@2c02e5c[MainActivity](19934): stopped(true) old=false
D/SurfaceView(19934): windowStopped(true) false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{57ae460 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,2136} of ViewRootImpl@2c02e5c[MainActivity]
D/FlutterView(19934): Detaching from a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@a4fd448
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(19934): Detaching FlutterEngine from the Activity that owns this Fragment.
D/FlutterEngine(19934): Destroying.
D/FlutterEnginePluginRegistry(19934): Destroying.
I/mali_egl(19934): eglDestroySurface() in
I/mali_egl(19934): eglDestroySurface() out
D/ViewRootImpl@2c02e5c[MainActivity](19934): dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputTransport(19934): Input channel destroyed: '274023 ', fd=93
D/AndroidRuntime(19934): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(19934): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(19934): Process: io.memoo.app, PID: 19934
E/AndroidRuntime(19934): java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot execute operation because FlutterJNI is not attached to native.
E/AndroidRuntime(19934):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.ensureAttachedToNative(FlutterJNI.java:227)
E/AndroidRuntime(19934):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.markTextureFrameAvailable(FlutterJNI.java:554)
E/AndroidRuntime(19934):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.renderer.FlutterRenderer.markTextureFrameAvailable(FlutterRenderer.java:274)
E/AndroidRuntime(19934):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.renderer.FlutterRenderer.access$300(FlutterRenderer.java:38)
E/AndroidRuntime(19934):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.renderer.FlutterRenderer$SurfaceTextureRegistryEntry$1.onFrameAvailable(FlutterRenderer.java:145)
E/AndroidRuntime(19934):    at android.graphics.SurfaceTexture$1.handleMessage(SurfaceTexture.java:211)
E/AndroidRuntime(19934):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(19934):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(19934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8016)
E/AndroidRuntime(19934):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(19934):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime(19934):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
I/Process (19934): Sending signal. PID: 19934 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Sorry for the block of text, but I've posted the whole log from the moment I press the back button. I sadly couldn't make anything from it.

#### Note

The home button works as expected. It puts the app into drawer and resumes it later with no errors.
The error is present on release build also. I'm testing it on Samsung Galaxy s10e with Android 10.

#### Flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.778], locale sl-SI)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.43.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved it already or if anyone else runs into this but I managed to get mine working with this function implemented in the class that is located in the Android folder.

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
  private val CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.dev/battery"

  override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
      call, result ->
      // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
      // TODO
    }
  }
}
```

This function was extracted from the flutter documentation from the following link:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-kotlin-tab#step-3-add-an-android-platform-specific-implementation

On Step 3, it demonstrates how to implement any Android native libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the latest plugin version and then strictly followed their example. It then worked without a problem.

Before, I had custom logic for initializing and disposing camera, and even though everything made sense, it didn't work.

Comment: Hey Jaka, it would be best if you included a summary of "their example" here just in case the example changes in the future.

Comment: I've created a gist https://gist.github.com/jrizmal/493c2fe2005a646f1171c1c241dc75dd